# Creating a bag/multiset from a list

Tags: haskell

This has got to be super easy and I'm missing something. I cant for the life of me think about how to do this. I need to create a bag from a list.
I tried:

```
ins n [] = [(n,1)]
ins n ((x,y):xys)
  |n == x    = (x, y + 1):xys
  |otherwise = (x,y): ins x xys

fromList [] = []
fromList (x:xs) = ins x [] : bag xs
```

This obviously doesnt work as intended and the recursion is working against me here. The insert function does actually work, but I cant figure out how to keep adding to the same list instead of what Im doing

Edit: probably should have been far more specific, apologies. Bag would be the data type where `Bag a = [(element, number of occurrences in list)]`
Possibly also known as multiset.
So the list [2,2,3,4,2,3], would become [(2,3),(3,2),(4,1)]

I'm very new to Haskell and programming in general so I apologize again for being abstract about it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a ‘bag’ here? I’ve vaguely heard of it as being a data structure, but when I look it up the only results are about a specific `Bag` class in Java.

Comment: @bradrn apologies mate, I've edited my post to be more specific

Comment: Thanks @BoomerNoobProgrammer! That makes it a lot easier to understand what you’re trying to do, and I think I can see where your error is now. Hint: in `fromList`, you’re currently adding each item to an empty list `[]`, when you should be adding to the bag you made in the recursion step (`fromList xs`).

Comment: Also in the recursive step of the `ins` function: `otherwise = (x,y): ins x xys`, `x` should be `n`. I.e. `otherwise = (x,y): ins n xys`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it.  What you probably want is:

```
fromList [] = []
fromList (x:xs) = ins x (fromList xs)
```

If you look at the types, it is easier to see what went wrong.  In the fixed version:

```
ins :: (Eq a, Num b) => a -> [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
fromList :: (Eq a, Num b) => [a] -> [(a,b)]
```

In the original version of `fromList`, you should get an error because `bag` is undefined; but assuming you meant:

```
fromList [] = []
fromList (x:xs) = ins x [] : fromList xs
```

the inferred type will be:

```
fromList :: (Eq a, Num b) => [a] -> [[(a,b)]]
```

Rather than returning the bag type `[(a,b)]`, it returns a list of bags, `[[(a,b)]]`.

What this version is actually doing is wrapping each element as a singleton bag; basically the same as `map (\ x -> ins x [])`.